# cmd.exe shortcuts and parameters

Tags: windows, script, command-line

I have made a shortcut that opens cmd at a specific directroy

How can I add a program to execute at the end of this statement?

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k cd  "C:\Program Files\App"
```

I have tried:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k cd  "C:\Program Files\App" "C:\Program Files\App\app.exe"
```

But it doesnt work

Comment: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "ping 8.8.8.8 -t"

         As an example, adding this in the target field of the shortcut would launch ping on clicking the shortcut.

Answer (score 14):

```
cmd /k "command1 && command2"
```

Also take a look at the [Microsoft documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490880.aspx#EBAA) for the command interpreter.

Answer (score 5):

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k cd  "C:\Program Files\App" & app
```

Since you're already in the directory there's no point in repeating it, so I just shortened your path to `app`. Anyways, use `&` to run multiple commands.

Comment: damn, thanks lol, I just tried && start "xxxx", didnt work, hopefully this will :)

Comment: @James: I've also edited, you can just use `& app` instead of the full path if you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you have cmd.exe run a script with the commands/programs you want. If it needs to be dynamic, you can make the directory name and the command to run parameters to the script.